# Why can't we pass a instance variable to the super class constructor?

Tags: java, scjp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot refer to a instance method while explicitly invoking a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685506/cannot-refer-to-a-instance-method-while-explicitly-invoking-a-constructor)

I have been trying to do this for long time.

```
public class bb extends test {

    int t = 23;

    public bb() {
        super(t); //**This is the place that error comes**
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public bb(int v) {
    }
}

public class test {

    public test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public test(int v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
class s {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        bb sd = new bb();
        System.out.println("sdfsdfsdfd");
    }
}
```

This is the error that comes. I want to know why a instance variable can't be passed to a super class constructor? I suspect that it's because there is no instance accessible to the constructor.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Cannot refer to an instance field t while explicitly invoking a constructor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make that variable as a `static` variable that error will disappear.. this happens because

`Instance Variables` are created once its constructor is called but here in this case before the

`child's constructor` its parent Constructor gets executed.. which means instance variables/object of

child class doesn't exist in the Heap. or in other words they are not constructed yet.. but in case

of `static variables` they are first one's getting executed thus they have some values and that works

perfectly fine..

Comment: I still have a problem I going to refer to it using a new question....Thanks for everything